# Clustering algorithm recommendations

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

So I have somewhat of a clustering problem. What you see in the image is a set of points that need to be classified or clustered in six rows. These particular points have already been classified, that is why they are coloured.

The current algorithm is custom made and essentially picks the leftmost point and looks for the next one in that row, picking the closest one  from the "candidate region" (lines drawn on bottom left point). I will not go over this much, but the algorithm sometimes fails particularily when there are multiple missing points (see points in red box to the right, those should be aqua blue)

I want to replace this with a Machine Learning based algorithm or clustering. I have tried knn but it was still not perfect, due to the non straight nature of the rows (I clustered the projections of the points but for small x axis windows, not the entire thing)

Is there a good Deep Clustering algorithm for this kind of application? I have a few hundred labeled sets of points, so I could go the supervised way.

From what I have researched, traditional clustering methods don't suit this very well. Also DNN classification models, because I have to input all the points at once, as row placement is context sensitive.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the "deep" algorithm? You seem to be asking about any applicable algorithm.

Comment: By Deep Clustering I meant a clustering algorithm using Deep Learning, which is what I have experience with (not the clustering part). Also since my clusters are non-linearly separable and sparse I assume no "traditional" clustering will work. In reality I ask for any applicable algorithm, but that was just my first instinct

Comment: Can you give an example of a deep clustering algorithm? I'm imagining something like using k-means on the encoded layer of an autoencoder. Or does this mean something else?

Comment: @Galen that is correct. Those are specified as DAE in [this survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.04142). However as I mentioned, any method that helps me effectively separate the rows is good to me.